# Encoding Uri using Link of react router dom not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to encode uri, using Link tag of react-router-dom but when I use javascript encodeURIComponent to encode uri it does not show encoded uri in address bar(url bar) though i see uri encoded when i hover.

```
<Link key={i}  to={encodeURIComponent(item.url)}> {item.text}</Link>
```

Am I mising anything or uri is decoded inside react router dom.

Comment: Try to fix like that `<Link key={i}  to={encodeURIComponent(item.url)}}> {item.text}</Link> `

Comment: Andrew I used the same...I edited my question...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Link in react router dom decodes the uri while pushing it to history.
Anybody can read this issue in github and related issues
**Path is decoded in createLocation #505**
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/505

I did workaround of this issue by double encoding the uri so that it is decoded once while pushing in history.
       encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(item.url))
till now I have not found any side effects of this....hope this helps anybody facing this issue.

Comment: Apologies I did found one side effect if someone right click and try to copy link address it will be encoded twice...and I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have a search bar that I need to push the search text to the URL using `history.push()` and so far I'm not able to encode it. It always ends up decoded in the URL.