# enocde uri in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, encodeuricomponent

Is there any way to encode the uri in `to` prop of `<Link>` in react router.

my code:

```
<Link to={`info/${props.movie.Title}`}> info </Link>
```

I have tried encodeURI() but it does not work.

```
uri = encodeURI(`info/${props.movie.Title}`)
console.log(uri);
<Link to={uri}> info </Link>
```

Clicking on the link gives the url as "http://localhost:3000/info/Man of Steel" as opposed to "http://localhost:3000/info/Man%20of%20Steel".
Is there a way to get the latter?

### Edit

React works perfectly. My bad. Firefox somehow doesn't encode spaces in URL bar. But other special characters get encoded. So my question changes to why are spaces not encoded by Firefox in the URL bar. I also noticed that copy pasting the link gives %20 instead of space.

### Edit 2

Firefox decodes spaces and displays it in the URL bar as opposed to other browsers which display %20. Encoding is actually done in the background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encoding Uri using Link of react router dom not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523058/encoding-uri-using-link-of-react-router-dom-not-working)

Comment: No. Issue is not solved by double encoding.

Comment: What do you mean by "somehow decodes it back again"? The target route should receive a decoded string via route props, that is a correct behaviour. Anyway I'd encode only the component, like `info/${encodeURIComponent(props.movie.Title)}`

Comment: @amik I have edited the question. Also yes i changed it to encodeURIComponent. But the result remains the same.

Comment: It seems to work. See https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-evm43 . You see `Man of steel` at the bottom of the browser when you hover over the link, however URL bar shows `Man%20of%20steel` when you click it.

Comment: It works in your link. But when i try it in my browser it shows spaces again. This means the problem isn't with react router then. Could it be something specific to Firefox or is it like that for local host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

encodeURIComponent() and React works perfectly. The issue was that the latest version of Firefox doesn't show space as encoded. It is encoded. Copy pasting it gives %20. But it will be displayed as space in Firefox URL bar. Other browsers still give %20.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I thought I was losing my mind but after checking in Chrome, this checks out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use some random string in URL address. Instead of it you can use id of movie ( info/:id ) and then get movie by id and show to user. As the result you don't need to decode string because it is not reliable

Comment: Yeah id makes more sense and there is no need to decode it. But why aren't spaces encoded? I want to know the reason behind it.

Comment: @CalvinWilson i've tried to reproduce your situation, but it works fine in last Chrome and in last FF on MacOS. Review the demo and give me feedback - https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-pond-09bce

Comment: It is a Firefox specific thing. It's not an actual error just displays space but it is encoded. It works in code sandbox but if you click the open in new window button there it displays spaces in Firefox URL bar. I use Firefox version 75 and Windows 10. It is not an error, just the way Firefox displays. But had me confused at the start.